# const reference to temporary variable and the mechanism behind

Tags: c++, reference, constants, lifetime, temporary

I've read many posts on const references but haven't found what I was looking for.
Could you please correct my assumption about the mechanism that binds temporary variable to const reference so that the lifetime is prolonged?

```
int Foo(){return 3;}

int main(){
const int& ref = Foo();
return 0;
}
```

`Foo` returns a temporary unnamed value that is located in a register and normally dismissed afterwards. Binding it to const reference tells the compiler not to dismiss it, but to save the value in memory with the scope of `ref` and the alias called `ref`.

Is this how it works ?

Comment: All that talk about registers and "memory" is an oversimplification in these modern times, especially when talking about languages like C++ that usually are compiled with powerful optimization. Just because you see something in the source, does not mean what ever it is needs to even exist, or exist in the place you may expect it to. For example, you code compiles to the equivalent of `int main () {return 0;}`. The `3` is never stored anywhere at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Foo returns temporary unnamed value

Correct.

> that is located in a register

Unspecified by the standard.

> and normally dismissed afterwards

Destroyed at the end of the full expression, to be more precise. If the lifetime wasn't extended by the reference that is.

Of course, integers do not have destructors, so the lifetime simply signifies whether the storage (if any) can be re-used or not.

> Binding it to const reference tells the compiler not to dismiss it, but to save the value in memory with the scope of ref

Correct. Binding a reference to a temporary extends the lifetime of that temporary to match the lifetime of the reference.

Answer (score 0):

The language doesn't really say how this is to be implemented, just how it should work, but you show one possible way of doing it.

Theoretically, nothing stops the compiler from keeping the temporary in a register and use `ref` as a name for it. So it doesn't *have to* store the value in memory.

Or, in this particular case, the compiler can see that the value will always be `3`, so it can replace all uses of `ref` by `3`, and not store anything anywhere.